# How can I make center this text div?

Tags: html, css

I have a block of images with a hover effect with text appearing. I am having trouble getting the text vertically aligned. It stays horizontal but I want it to stay responsively centered at all times.

```css
.content3{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
 display: block;
}

#staffbox1, #staffbox2,#staffbox3,#staffbox4, #staffbox5, #staffbox6,#staffbox7,#staffbox8{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
 font-size: 100%;
 color: #ffffff;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#staffbox1 img, #staffbox2 img,#staffbox3 img,#staffbox4 img, #staffbox5 img, #staffbox6 img,#staffbox7 img,#staffbox8 img{
 width: 100%; 
 display: block;
}

.staffboxcontent{
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}

#staffbox1:hover #emmatext, #staffbox2:hover #georgetext, #staffbox3:hover #tomtext, #staffbox4:hover #pollytext, #staffbox5:hover #racheltext, #staffbox6:hover #tomstext, #staffbox7:hover #pedrotext, #staffbox8:hover #allantext{
 display: block;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;  
 margin: 0 auto;
 -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

.text{
 position: absolute;
}

#staff{
 background-color: #e3e3e5;
 color: #000000;
 display: block;
 padding: 1px 0px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#emmatext, #georgetext, #tomtext, #pollytext, #racheltext, #tomstext, #pedrotext, #allantext{
 display: none;
 line-height: 0;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="content3" id="staffwrap">
    <header id="staff"><h2>MEET OUR STAFF</h2></header>
 <div id="staffbox1">
  <div class="staffboxcontent" id="staffboxcontent1">
   <div class="text" id="emmatext"><div id="textposition1"><header><h4>EMMA HUTCHISON</h4><h5>Creative Director</h5></header><p>Em’s been here since the start, along with our MD Gagey, she’s seen S&nbsp;C grow from 2 mates in a loft to the global agency spanning 3 continents you see before you today. She likes cats and works an average of 26hrs every day.</p></div>
   </div><img src="img/portrait4.png"></div> 
 </div>
 <div id="staffbox2">
  <div class="staffboxcontent">
   <div class="text" id="georgetext"><div id="textposition2"><header><h4>GEORGE HIGHAM</h4><h5>Head of Design</h5></header><p>George has been here for over 2 years now and makes everything look pretty. He loves bright colours and playing party tunes all day long.</p></div>
  </div><img src="img/portrait2.png"></div>
 </div>
  <div id="staffbox3">
  <div class="staffboxcontent">
   <div class="text" id="tomtext"><div id="textposition3"><header><h4>TOM LOWLES</h4><h5>Junior Designer</h5></header><p>Tom joined us in the summer of 2016. Assist's George in making things look pretty and he just loves to fall of his skateboard and draw drawings.</p></div>
  </div><img src="img/portrait1.png"></div>
 </div>
  <div id="staffbox4">
  <div class="staffboxcontent">
   <div class="text" id="pollytext"><div id="textposition4"><header><h4>POLLY BRYSON</h4><h5>Production Coordinator</h5></header><p>Polly deals with all things production, joining the company in early 2016. She loves making the office round of hot toddies and is always cooking up some delicious healthy concoction.</p></div>
  </div><img src="img/portrait6.png"></div>
 </div>
   <div id="staffbox5">
  <div class="staffboxcontent">
   <div class="text" id="racheltext"><div id="textposition5"><header><h4>RACHEL LAI</h4><h5>Account Manager</h5></header><p>Polly deals with all things production, joining the company in early 2016. She loves making the office round of hot toddies and is always cooking up some delicious healthy concoction.</p></div>
  </div><img src="img/portrait7.png"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="staffbox6">
  <div class="staffboxcontent">
   <div class="text" id="tomstext"><div id="textposition6"><header><h4>TOM SODEN</h4><h5>Consultancy Director</h5></header><p>Polly deals with all things production, joining the company in early 2016. She loves making the office round of hot toddies and is always cooking up some delicious healthy concoction.</p></div>
  </div><img src="img/portrait5.png"></div>
 </div>
  <div id="staffbox7">
  <div class="staffboxcontent">
   <div class="text" id="pedrotext"><div id="textposition7"><header><h4>PEDRO GARVOA</h4><h5>Consultant</h5></header><p>Polly deals with all things production, joining the company in early 2016. She loves making the office round of hot toddies and is always cooking up some delicious healthy concoction.</p></div>
  </div><img src="img/portrait8.png"></div>
 </div>
  <div id="staffbox8">
  <div class="staffboxcontent">
   <div class="text" id="allantext"><div id="textposition8"><header><h4>ALLAN GAGE</h4><h5>Director</h5></header><p>Polly deals with all things production, joining the company in early 2016. She loves making the office round of hot toddies and is always cooking up some delicious healthy concoction.</p></div>
  </div><img src="img/portrait3.png"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your problem is the line-height: 0  and the position: absolute. Just remove line-height:0 and the text will be shown as expected.

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning if you don't know exactly how it works

Comment: (And very few people know exactly how absolute positioning works before trying to use it the first few times.)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Using position: absolute is the only way I can find to have the text on top of the image. When I remove the line height it doesn't change anything. 

Re not knowing how it works... I am sorry for not being a pro, hence why I am on this site asking for help. Trying my best to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `flexbox` for this, You can add following CSS

```
.staffboxcontent {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood your concern.

if .text position is absolute please also specify (top, left, bottom, right)

It will be feasible to try position:
 relative.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this with

```
h4{
 margin-top:auto;
 margin-bottom:auto;}
```

You may have to play around with the hover box height to get all the text in.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I managed to fix the problem using the following solution of using the following css for all of the #textpositions.

```
position:relative;
line-height: 1.5;
height: auto;
width: 70%;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -70%);
```